# What the difference between save and insert when wanting to create new record in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

What is the difference between `.save()` and `.insert()` in the `Repository` when wanting to create a new record?

In the code, the [comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/b6c828cc6c9786c155165d97e1f21af7cf423075/src/repository/Repository.ts#L224-L232) for `.insert()` is:

```
// From https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/b6c828cc6c9786c155165d97e1f21af7cf423075/src/repository/Repository.ts#L224-L232


    /**
     * Inserts a given entity into the database.
     * Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included.
     * Executes fast and efficient INSERT query.
     * Does not check if entity exist in the database, so query will fail if duplicate entity is being inserted.
     */
    insert(entity: QueryDeepPartialEntity<Entity>|(QueryDeepPartialEntity<Entity>[])): Promise<InsertResult> {
        return this.manager.insert(this.metadata.target as any, entity);
    }
```

In the code, the [comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/b6c828cc6c9786c155165d97e1f21af7cf423075/src/repository/Repository.ts#L140-L151) for `.save()` is:

```
// From https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/b6c828cc6c9786c155165d97e1f21af7cf423075/src/repository/Repository.ts#L140-L151

    /**
     * Saves a given entity in the database.
     * If entity does not exist in the database then inserts, otherwise updates.
     */
    save<T extends DeepPartial<Entity>>(entity: T, options?: SaveOptions): Promise<T & Entity>;

    /**
     * Saves one or many given entities.
     */
    save<T extends DeepPartial<Entity>>(entityOrEntities: T|T[], options?: SaveOptions): Promise<T|T[]> {
        return this.manager.save<Entity, T>(this.metadata.target as any, entityOrEntities as any, options);
    }
```

I don't understand what does:

> *Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included.*
>
> From `.insert()` comment

means

Comment: The documentation's grammar needs improving, but it means that invoking `.insert` will save a single entity (i.e. a single row in a single table), whereas `.save` will insert all pending entities in all affected tables. This difference is useful when you need to work-around limitations in different databases w.r.t. deferred-constraints.

Comment: The comment sound a little bit like: no side effect by TypeORM will be done, only inserting using INSERT

Comment: So in your interpersonal, relations won't be saved (e.g creating new album with images, when images are in different table)